# The method (double[]) in the type main is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find a median of an array in Java.

I am getting the exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

The method median(double[]) in the type tez3 is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

at tez3.main(tez3.java:33)

My code is below. What is the problem? How can i print the double function ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class tez3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\tny\\Deneme1.txt"));
        int[] numberList = new int[10];
        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int result = 0;
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            numberList[i++] = s.nextInt();
        }
        for (i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(+(i + 1) + ".Value: " + numberList[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {
            count++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {
            result += numberList[i];
        }

        System.out.println("Average of the Values is: " + result / count);
        System.out.println("Mode of the Values is: " + mode(numberList));
        System.out.println("Median of the Values is: " + median(numberList));
    }

    public static int mode(int numberList[]) {
        int maxValue = 0, maxCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length; ++i) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < numberList.length; ++j) {
                if (numberList[j] == numberList[i]) {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                maxValue = numberList[i];
            }
        }

        return maxValue;
    }

    public double median(double[] numberList) {
        int factor = numberList.length - 1;
        double[] first = new double[(double) factor / 2];
        double[] last = new double[first.length];
        double[] middleNumbers = new double[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
            first[i] = numbersList[i];
        }
        for (int i = numberList.length; i > last.length; i--) {
            last[i] = numbersList[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= numberList.length; i++) {
            if (numberList[i] != first[i] || numberList[i] != last[i]) {
                middleNumbers[i] = numberList[i];
            }
        }
        if (numberList.length % 2 == 0) {
            double total = middleNumbers[0] + middleNumbers[1];
            return total / 2;
        } else {
            return middleNumbers[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript is not Java. Please make an effort to figure out the language you're writing code in.

Comment: `java != javascript`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error message says. Your method median() takes a double[] as parameter.

But when you're trying to call it you give it numberList as a parameter. But numberList is an int[], that is to say it is not a double[].

The easiest fix is to modify median() so that the parameter it takes is int[] rather than double[].

Comment: i create a new array using double but i get "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method median(double[]) from the type tez3" error. Is there anything to do about it or i just modify median with int like you said ?

Comment: @MeltemÇomak that's a new error. Just like your method mode() is static, your method median() should be too. That or you should rework the whole code to make neither of them static.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to cast all elements in you int[] list to a double.
If you don't want to change the parameters of median to int[] then my preferred way to deal with this is to overload the method and convert the arguments

So, it would be something like:

```
    public double median(int[] numberList) {
        double[] doubleList = new double[numberList.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<doubleList.size(); i++){
            doubleList[i] = (double)numberList[i];
        }
        return median(doubleList);
    }
```

If you did change the parameter of your original 'median' method, then you would just cast the numberList element each time you called it, i.e.

```
    first[i] = (double) numbersList[i];
```